# Python matplotlib plot missing on WSL

Tags: python, matplotlib, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm starting with *matplotlib* and when i execute the code from first tutorial:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # Create a figure containing a single axes.
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2, 3]);  # Plot some data on the axes.
```

I get

```
[Done] exited with code=0 in 2.456 seconds
```

But i never see the plot, what i'm missing?
I'm using Python3.6.9 on WSL:Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS on my W11

Comment: WSL isn't able to show dialogs. WSL2 is. (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps). Please verify you're using WSL2

Comment: Thanks @kabooya totally works!